# Invoking an initialized (not null) delegate produces a NullReferenceException (in a Windows service)

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, windows-services

For some reason i have a hard time calling a delegate method from within a thread in Windows service.  Don't think environment makes that much of a difference, but want you to understand why i can't just step through this code in debugger (trace-logging is quite possible though).  Below is a simplified outline; all i want is to execute a callback from the main class to deal with received data (my desire is to separate data-processing implementation [involving too many other dependencies] from *BaseSvc*'s library code):

```
public class    BaseSvc         // library class (separate DLL)
{
    public delegate     bool    dlProcCmd( byte[] bData );
    public static   dlProcCmd   fnProcCmd;

    public static void      Start( )                                // 1
//  public static void      Start( BaseSvc.dlProcCmd ProcCmd )      // 2
    {
//      BaseSvc.fnProcCmd=  ProcCmd;                                // 2
        ..
        bListen=    true;
        thTcpComm=  new Thread( new ThreadStart( TcpComm ) );
        thTcpComm.Start( );
    }
    ..
    public static void      TcpComm( )
    {
        ..
        while(  bListen  )
        {
            ..
            if(  fnProcCmd != null  )
            {
                Utils.Log( fnProcCmd.Method.ToString( ) );
                    // prints:Boolean ProcCmd(Byte[])
                fnProcCmd( bData );     // throws:
                    // Void TcpComm():  System.NullReferenceException
                    // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            }
        }
    }
    ..
}
```

..

```
public partial class    WinSvc : ServiceBase        // SCM-compatible .exe
{
    /// <summary>Handles Start command</summary>
    protected override void     OnStart( string[] args )
    {
        BaseSvc.fnProcCmd=  ProcCmd;                                // 1a
//      BaseSvc.fnProcCmd=  new BaseSvc.dlProcCmd( ProcCmd );       // 1b
//      BaseSvc.fnProcCmd+= new BaseSvc.dlProcCmd( ProcCmd );       // 1c
        BaseSvc.Start( );                                           // 1
//      BaseSvc.Start( new BaseSvc.dlProcCmd( ProcCmd ) );          // 2
        ..
    }

    public bool     ProcCmd( byte[] bData )
    {
        ..
        return  true;
    }
}
```

At first i thought smth is wrong with declaration or initialization of the delegate method, so various tries are marked with 1a, 1b, 1c and 2.  However, in either scenario i end up with a trace printout confirming that `if( fnProcCmd != null )` check passed, followed by a NullRefException.  *bData* argument is initialized at that moment, 100% guaranteed and confirmed by tracing, so that leaves only `fnProcCmd` as the culprit.  But it is initialized, is it not!?  What am i missing here??

Could it be that the execution context for *WinSvc* class is different from that of *BaseSvc*, and/or that `TcpComm( )` executes in its own thread?  I'd expect a more intuitive error in that case..

I must be doing smth wrong.  What should i do to enable such a callback?

**UPDATE**:  After Henk's suggestion i commented out `ProcCmd`'s body and the problem disappeared, => issue is within that code and has nothing to do with the delegate mechanism.  Sorry for confusion.
(BTW, using delegate via scenario 1a works fine.)

Comment: Can you convert your code to a short but complete program?

Comment: And you are also sure that the function/method that is being called has no null-reference? Try calling that function directly, with the parameters.

Comment: Your code looks OK, so the problem is probably elsewhere... Try to get the stacktrace from the exception and disclose amap from ProcCmd(). Have you tried with an empty ProcCmd() ?

Comment: Thank you guys for ideas!  @JonSkeet, i'll try to create a sample (existing codebase is quite big).
Virtlink, i'm *hoping* that be it null the if-branch shouldn't execute at all (and => should be no trace output).  Purpose of this callback is to decouple ProcCmd, don't see an easy way to call directly into "parent" class (hence scenario 2, providing direct reference to constructor);  but i'll try.
HenkHolterman, didn't try with empty ProcCmd yet (*expecting* that if exception is inside - it should be reported as such), will try that too;  and expose entire StackTrace.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, you are spot on!  `ProcCmd( )` didn't have its own try-catch, and commenting out its code immediately removed the problem.  This exposed an issue with my std. exception logging (to minimize log-size i was limiting StackTrace to a single line - this part needs improvement :).

Thanks again to everyone!  Henk, I'd be happy to accept your suggestion as answer if you make it such!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this part:

```
        if(  fnProcCmd != null  )
        {
            Utils.Log( fnProcCmd.Method.ToString( ) );
                // prints:Boolean ProcCmd(Byte[])
            fnProcCmd( bData );     // throws:
                // Void TcpComm():  System.NullReferenceException
                // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        }
```

The null-checking on `fnProcCmd` is extensive and convincing so it must be something happening inside `ProcCmd()` .

To home in on the error, try it with an empty ProcCmd() :

```
 public bool     ProcCmd( byte[] bData )
 {
    //    ...
    //
    //    ...
    return  true;
 }
```